# How set AngularJS model value inside async call, custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want change value of input element AND assigned value in model, inside async validator directive.

```
angular
    .module('lion.Form_Validator')
    .directive('phoneValidation', Lion_Form_Validator_Phone)

function Lion_Form_Validator_Phone($q, $http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrib, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.phone = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                if (ngModel.$isEmpty(modelValue))
                    return $q.when();

                $http.get('/?check-phone-numbers=' + modelValue, {cache: true}).then(function (res) {
                    if (!res.data.valid) {
                        deferred.reject();
                    } else {
                        /*********************/
                        // here want change the value of input and model
                        //element.val(res.data.phone); -> this not update the model

                        deferred.resolve();
                    }
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Sample HTML code:

```
<div data-ng-controller="BalanceController as balance">
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" data-phone-validation="" data-ng-model="balance.form.phone">
</div>
```

Comment: Read up about some documentation about the `ngModelController`, which you already use. You can do something like `ngModel.$setViewValue(res.data.phone)`

Comment: @Blackfire Try using scope instead of element bass

Comment: Directive definitely isn't a right place to call API. Why do you would like to have it?

Comment: only the view changed, not the model:
ngModel.$setViewValue(res.data.phone); 
ngModel.$render();

same:
ngModel.$modelValue = res.data.phone;

Comment: try scope.$apply with scope.$eval, same problem

Comment: @Akarienta Because this is a simple custom form validator, just the regexp too complex, only work in PHP, not in Javascript. (plus give some number formatting)